# How process hierarchy works in macOS

Tags: terminal, unix, activity-monitor, macos

I'm wondering how `Activity Monitor` relates these two process if the child (Safari Web Content) doesn't have the `ppid` of the main one (Safari). `pstree`, which uses the `ppid` to organize the tree, shows no relation between them.

[image: Safari process tree]

Here's another example, `caffeinate` was launched from a shell script inside `BetterTouchTool` using `nohup`, and again `pstree` doesn't show any relation.

[image: caffeinate process tree]

Actually what I need is to send a `kill` signal to "childs" like `Safari Web Content` using `shell script` or `C` api knowing only the "Safari" `pid`. And I think this might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Safari "child" processes are actually children of the init system (`launchd` which has PID `1`) which explains why `pstree` or other such unix tools cannot make use of the usual parent pid (or process group) relation:

[image: activity monitor process listing]

```
% ps axo pid,ppid | egrep '81921|81925|82022'
81921     1
81925     1
82022     1
```

Instead you will need to use an Apple API; the `launchctl` utility indicates that the "domain" or "ASID" may be relevant:

```
% sudo launchctl procinfo 82022 | grep -1 81921

        domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Safari.81921
        asid = 100006
--
--

responsible pid = 81921
responsible unique pid = 81921
responsible path = /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

But let's post this info before testing what something like `launchctl kill ...` does.

(Also note the above is from Mac OS X 10.11.6, the interfaces may have been changed by Apple since then.)

Comment: The API is `responsibility_get_pid_responsible_for_pid` from libquarantine.